# Ubuntu 22 disable multipath during installation

Tags: ubuntu, multipath-storage

I have a server platform with a set of NVMe drives. I am trying to install Ubuntu 22 on one of the drives and mount the other as a data drive later. But on the Ubuntu installation GUI, it shows up as a single multipath device. I went to the Shell and tried doing `multipath -F,` but then the device went away altogether. I also tried blacklisting the device then `systemctl reload multipathd.service` but no luck. How do I go about it? Although I have other storage drives on the machine, I want to avoid using them. Thanks.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try Formatting Each Drive using GParted or similar before running the Ubuntu installer, then when asked use Custom as the partition layout.

Comment: Thanks @eyou Tried it just now. Unfortunately

Comment: Thanks @eyoung100. Went on shell, did the following 

parted /dev/nvme0n1 mklabel gpt; parted -a opt /dev/nvme0n1 mkpart primary ext4 0% 100%; mkfs.ext4 -L disk0 /dev/nvme0n1

Then the device does not show up at all. Can you share some steps on how to format it?

Comment: Do you have the Ubuntu Installation media?  If so start it in Live Mode (Don't start the Installer, then search the Gnome apps for GParted,  Once you've got that open we can start

Comment: Thanks @eyoung100. Does this work for Servers also? i see option "Try or install", but not sure if there's anything similar to the desktop live boot one.

Comment: Choose Try.  The Server Variant doesn't have a desktop.  If you're still having issues Google for "GParted Live CD"  Apologies, I just reread server